# проблемы java hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

первый раз делаю hibernate возникла ошибка. В java новичок подскажите куда копать.

```
янв 10, 2019 8:09:32 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.0.Final}
янв 10, 2019 8:09:32 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Failed to create sessionFactory object.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/bytebuddy/NamingStrategy$SuffixingRandom$BaseNameResolver
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at employee.ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/bytebuddy/NamingStrategy$SuffixingRandom$BaseNameResolver
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.buildBytecodeProvider(Environment.java:345)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.buildBytecodeProvider(Environment.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.reset(Configuration.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:118)
    at employee.ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.bytebuddy.NamingStrategy$SuffixingRandom$BaseNameResolver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 9 more
    C:\Users\alsem\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
    СБОРКА ЗАВЕРШЕНА СО СБОЕМ (общее время: 2 секунды)
```

и собственно файлы

```
package employee;

import java.util.List; 
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator; 

import org.hibernate.HibernateException; 
import org.hibernate.Session; 
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class ManageEmployee {
   private static SessionFactory factory; 
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      try {
         factory = new Configuration().
                   configure().
                   //addPackage("com.xyz") //add package if used.
                   addAnnotatedClass(Employee.class).
                   buildSessionFactory();
      } catch (Throwable ex) { 
         System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
         throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex); 
      }

      ManageEmployee ME = new ManageEmployee();




      Integer empID1 = ME.addEmployee("Zara", "Ali", 1000);
      Integer empID2 = ME.addEmployee("Daisy", "Das", 5000);
      Integer empID3 = ME.addEmployee("John", "Paul", 10000);




      ME.listEmployees();


      ME.updateEmployee(empID1, 5000);


      ME.deleteEmployee(empID2);

      ME.listEmployees();
   }

   public Integer addEmployee(String fname, String lname, int salary){
      Session session = factory.openSession();
      Transaction tx = null;
      Integer employeeID = null;

      try {
         tx = session.beginTransaction();
         Employee employee = new Employee();
         employee.setFirstName(fname);
         employee.setLastName(lname);
         employee.setSalary(salary);
         employeeID = (Integer) session.save(employee); 
         tx.commit();
      } catch (HibernateException e) {
         if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      } finally {
         session.close(); 
      }
      return employeeID;
   }




   public void listEmployees( ){
      Session session = factory.openSession();
      Transaction tx = null;

      try {
         tx = session.beginTransaction();
         List employees = session.createQuery("FROM Employee").list(); 
         for (Iterator iterator = employees.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
            Employee employee = (Employee) iterator.next(); 
            System.out.print("First Name: " + employee.getFirstName()); 
            System.out.print("  Last Name: " + employee.getLastName()); 
            System.out.println("  Salary: " + employee.getSalary()); 
         }
         tx.commit();
      } catch (HibernateException e) {
         if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      } finally {
         session.close(); 
      }
   }




   public void updateEmployee(Integer EmployeeID, int salary ){
      Session session = factory.openSession();
      Transaction tx = null;

      try {
         tx = session.beginTransaction();
         Employee employee = (Employee)session.get(Employee.class, EmployeeID); 
         employee.setSalary( salary );
         session.update(employee); 
         tx.commit();
      } catch (HibernateException e) {
         if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      } finally {
         session.close(); 
      }
   }

   public void deleteEmployee(Integer EmployeeID){
      Session session = factory.openSession();
      Transaction tx = null;

      try {
         tx = session.beginTransaction();
         Employee employee = (Employee)session.get(Employee.class, EmployeeID); 
         session.delete(employee); 
         tx.commit();
      } catch (HibernateException e) {
         if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      } finally {
         session.close(); 
      }
   }
} 



package employee;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {
   @Id @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name = "id")
   private int id;

   @Column(name = "first_name")
   private String firstName;

   @Column(name = "last_name")
   private String lastName;

   @Column(name = "salary")
   private int salary; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    }
    public int getId() {
      return id;
   }

   public void setId( int id ) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   public String getFirstName() {
      return firstName;
   }

   public void setFirstName( String first_name ) {
      this.firstName = first_name;
   }

   public String getLastName() {
      return lastName;
   }

   public void setLastName( String last_name ) {
      this.lastName = last_name;
   }

   public int getSalary() {
      return salary;
   }

   public void setSalary( int salary ) {
      this.salary = salary;
   }
}
```

`

и собственно hibernate.cfg.xml

`

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>

    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost/music_shop</property>   
    <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="connection.password">postgres</property>
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <property name= "cache.provider_class">
        org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
    </property>
      <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
      <property name="show_sql">true</property>
      <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
      <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

   </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

`

Comment: INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found

Comment: это что-нибудь для вас значит?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка, похоже, возникает в этой строке:

```
addAnnotatedClass(Employee.class).
```

Ваш класс Employee описан аннотациями? Приложите его.